# how to know uiwebview's progress

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

I have a webview which hits a website with 3 or 4 frames. I am not able to find the real end of the page loading. Is there is way to find out the progress of the webpage downloading precisely ?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the `UIWebViewDelegate` [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html). You can find out when the UIWebView finishes loading with [-webViewDidFinishLoad:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webViewDidFinishLoad%3a) Other than that, I think you're pretty limited to the API's available in `UIWebView` and `UIWebViewDelegate`.